# $scope gets null after calling template in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

i have a nested directive like this

```
app.directive('grid', ['$log', '$http', function ($log , $http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        //template: '<span></span>', //i uncomment this line
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs){
            var swColumns = [];
            this.setColumns = function (columns) {
                swColumns = columns;
                $log.log('grid controller');
                $log.log(columns);
                $scope.swColDefs = columns;
                $log.log($scope.swColDefs);
            };

            this.getColumns = function () {
                return swColumns;
            };
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, gridController) {
            $log.log('grid link');
            $log.log(gridController.getColumns());
            $log.log(scope.swColDefs);
        }
    };
}]);
app.directive('gridColumns', ['$log', function ($log) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: ['^grid', 'gridColumns'],
        controller: function () {
            var columns = [];
            this.addColumns = function (column) {
                columns.push(column);
            };
            this.getColumns = function () {
                return columns;
            };
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
            var gridController = controllers[0];
            var gridColumnsController = controllers[1];
            gridController.setColumns(gridColumnsController.getColumns());
        }
    };
}]);
```

every thing is ok until i uncomment the template in grid directive
after that the swColDefs in grid link function become an empty array
what is wrong with my code ?

```
<grid>
  <grid-columns>
  </grid-columns>
  ...
</grid>
```

and i am using it like this

Comment: could you create a plunkr/fiddle of the same?

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If not, please clarify in comments.

Comment: I did what you said and a little bit change in my child directive and the problem was solved thank you @NewDev

Comment: @davmszd, how is your change different from the first suggestion I gave?

Comment: @NewDev I put the ng-tranclude div  in span as i mentioned in template

Comment: Fine, but conceptually it is the exact same solution, so not sure why it warranted a separate answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by doing this in grid template
first i add a div with ng-transclude to the template 
secod transclude : true in grid directive

```
app.directive('grid', ['$log', '$http', function ($log , $http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        transclude:true,//my change
        template: '<span>
                   <div ng-transclude>//my change
                   </div>
                   </span>',
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs){
            var swColumns = [];
            this.setColumns = function (columns) {
                swColumns = columns;
                $log.log('grid controller');
                $log.log(columns);
                $scope.swColDefs = columns;
                $log.log($scope.swColDefs);
            };

            this.getColumns = function () {
                return swColumns;
            };
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, gridController) {
            $log.log('grid link');
            $log.log(gridController.getColumns());
            $log.log(scope.swColDefs);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the question doesn't specify, I'm assuming you're using your directive like so:

```
<grid>
  <grid-columns>
  </grid-columns>
  ...
</grid>
```

But since you're specifying a template of `<grid>`, Angular removes the contents and sets the template instead. And so, `gridColumns` directive never compiles and the `link` function never runs.

This is where transclusion is needed on `grid`. Transclusion takes the content out of DOM, compiles it (at compile-phase) and then allows you to link it against whatever scope you need and place it in the contents.

It's not clear from your question what scope `gridColumns` directive needs be linked against, and whether it has any visual components.

For a simple transclusion case, this can be done with `<ng-transclude>` in the template of `grid`:

```
transclude: true,
template: "<span>whatever</span><div ng-transclude></div>" // template of grid
```

Or, for more precise control over scope and placement you can use the `transclude` function (passed as a fifth parameter to the `link` function):

```
transclude: true,
template: "<span>whatever</span>",
link: function(scope, element, attrs, gridController, transclude){
  transclude(function(transcludedContent){
     // place the content where needed, if at all
  });
}
```